# Thread safe enqueue and dequeue method in Queue

Tags: java, algorithm, multithreading, thread-safety

As an exercise, I have implemented a linked queue whose `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods are synchronized. There is a `Producer` thread which keeps inserting elements into the queue as long as there are less than 10 items in it. When the queue is full, the thread waits. The second thread `Consumer` keep removing elements  from queue as long as it is not empty. I would like to get a review of this code - is there any flaw? How could I improve it?

MyLinkedQueue.java

```
public class MyLinkedQueue<T> implements Iterable<T> {
  private Node first, last;
  private int size = 0;
  private static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10;
  public Iterator<T> iterator() { return new QueueIterator(); }

  private class Node {
    T item;
    Node next;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() { return first == null; }
  public boolean isFull() { return MAX_QUEUE_SIZE == size(); }

  public synchronized void enqueue(T item) throws InterruptedException {
      while (isFull()) {
        wait();
      }

      Node oldLast = last;
      last = new Node();
      last.item = item;
      last.next = null;

      if (isEmpty()) {
        first = last;
      } else {
        oldLast.next = last;
      }
      notifyAll();
      size++;
    }

  public synchronized T dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
      while (0 == size()) {
        wait();
      }

      T item = first.item;
      first = first.next;

      if (isEmpty()) { last = null; }
      size--;
      notifyAll();
      return item;
    }

  public synchronized int size() { return size; }

  private class QueueIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    private Node current = first;

    public boolean hasNext() { return current != null; }
    public void remove() {}
    public T next() {
      T item = current.item;
      current = current.next;
      return item;
    }
  }
}
```

Producer.java

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
  private static final int DELAY = 1000;
  private MyLinkedQueue queue;
  private int count;

  public Producer(MyLinkedQueue queue, int count) {
    this.queue = queue;
    this.count = count;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        queue.enqueue(new Date().toString());
        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
      }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Consumer.java

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
  private static final int DELAY = 1000;
  private MyLinkedQueue queue;
  private int count;

  public Consumer(MyLinkedQueue queue, int count) {
    this.queue = queue;
    this.count = count;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        queue.dequeue();
        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
      }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

QueueThreadrunner.java

```
public class QueueThreadrunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyLinkedQueue queue = new MyLinkedQueue();
    final int THREADS = 10;
    final int REPETITIONS = 50;

    for (int i = 1; i <= THREADS; ++i) {
      Producer pr = new Producer(queue, REPETITIONS);
      Consumer cr = new Consumer(queue, REPETITIONS);

      Thread dt = new Thread(pr);
      Thread wt = new Thread(cr);

      dt.start();
      wt.start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `public boolean isEmpty() { return first == null; }` needs to be synchronized otherwise it could have a stale version of `first`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is apparent that you have put some thought in to this implementation, and apart from the not-synchronized isEmpty() method, it all looks functional.

I have some minor nit-picks though, and please bear in mind that these are just my opinion...

I prefer to have the notifyAll method to be the last thing in a synchronized block, where possible... You have:

```
....
  }
  notifyAll();
  size++;
}
```

I would always put the notifyAll() after the size++. This does not make a functional difference to the program, but it makes the logic more apparent (that `size++` will happen **before** any other thread can read the `size` value):

```
....
  }
  size++;
  notifyAll();
}
```

As I say, this does not affect the logic of the code, but it does affect the readability.

A second nit-pick I have is that you 'leak' logic from your synchronized blocks. What I mean by this, is that you should try to avoid any method calls from inside the block. When you call other methods from a block it becomes much easier to introduce synchronization bugs and deadlocks. Additionally, the methods you call are also synchronized, so you introduce a readability/complexity (and perhaps even a slight performance) issue by having nested synchronization calls.

EDIT: I would add another nit-pick here which is you do not use 'final' enough. 'final' is a good hint to the optimizer in Java and it allows it to make smarter choices when inlining and otherwise rearranging/compiling your code

Finally, I would choose just one mechanism to manage the empty/full condition of the queue. Currently you have a few: `isEmpty` depends on `first == null`; `isFull()` depends on `size == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE`; in your `enqueue(...)` you test for `isFull()` and `isEmpty()`; and in your `dequeue()` you test for `0 == size()` and `isEmpty()`. I would reduce all of these to tests on `size` only. That way there is only one condition that you need to mentally track when you read the code.

So, if it were me, I would replace your code as follows:

```
public synchronized boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; } // replace first == null
public synchronized boolean isFull()  { return size == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE; } // replace size()

public synchronized void enqueue(final T item) throws InterruptedException { // add final
  while (size == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {  // replace isFull() call.
    wait();
  }

  final Node oldLast = last; // add final
  last = new Node();
  last.item = item;
  last.next = null;

  if (size == 0) { // remove isEmpty()
    first = last;
  } else {
    oldLast.next = last;
  }
  size++; // move before notifyAll()
  notifyAll();
}    

public synchronized T dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
  while (size == 0) { // remove size() call.
    wait();
  }

  final T item = first.item; // add final
  first = first.next;

  size--; // move size-- up a bit to make the logic below more transparent
  if (size == 0) { // remove isEmpty() call
      last = null;
  }
  notifyAll();
  return item;
}
```

Finally, if it really was me, I would recommend that you consider [ReentrantLocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and [Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to manage the queue.... There's a good example (almost identical to this exact problem) of how to do it [in the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).